# how to convert a 2D numpy array to a 2D numpy matrix by changing shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have been struggling with changing a 2D numpy array to a 2D numpy matrix. I know that I can use     numpy.asmatrix(x)   to change array x into a matrix, however, the size for the matrix is not the size I wish to have. For example, I want to have a numpy.matrix((2,10)). It is easier for me to use two separate numpy.arrays to form each rows of the matrix. then I used numpy.append to put these two arrays into a matrix. However, when I use numpy.asmatrix to make this 2d array into a 2d matrix, the size is not the same size as my matrix (my desired matrix should have a size of 2*10 but when I change arrays to matrix, the size is 1*2). Does anybody know how I can change size of this asmatrix to my desired size?

code (a and b are two numpy.matrix with size of (1*10)):

```
    m=10
    c=sorted(random.sample(range(m),2))
    n1=numpy.array([a[0:c[0]],b[c[0]:c[1]],a[c[1]:]])
    n2=numpy.array([b[0:c[0]],a[c[0]:c[1]],b[c[1]:]]) 
    n3=numpy.append(n1,n2)
    n3=numpy.asmatrix(n3)
```

n1 and n2 are each arrays with shape 3 and n3 is matrix with shape 6. I want n3 to be a matrix with size 2*10

Thanks

Comment: Please add some example code...

Comment: *"I want to have a numpy.matrix((2,10))"* contradicts *"my desired matrix should have a size of 2*100"*. Please clarify.

Comment: @poli_g I put some codes in the discription. Thanks for your help

Comment: @unutbu I had a typo which I fixed. thank you